# how to get src of image using XPATH in selenium python

Tags: python, image, selenium, web-scraping, src

Hi I need the src of image using XPATH in selenium

```
src.getAttribute("src")
img-src= driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//img[contains(@class,'_3me- _3mf1 img')]")
x=img-src.getAttribute("src")
print(x)
```

src of all images of a page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

find_elements will return list so use find_element.

```
imgsrc= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[contains(@class,'_3me- _3mf1 img')]")
x=imgsrc.get_attribute("src")
print(x)
```

or if you want to use find_elements try this.

```
imgsrc= driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//img[contains(@class,'_3me- _3mf1 img')]")
for ele in imgsrc:
  x=ele.get_attribute("src")
  print(x)
```

Comment: for doing that i just get first image of that page but they have many images and I need All it

Answer (score 1):

From your code trials presumably you are trying to print the **src** attributes of the `<img>` elements having the `class` attribute as `_3me-`, `_3mf1` and `img`. But the `class` attributes `_3me-` and `_3mf1` are not **static** and are dynamically generated. So as a closest bet you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print([ele.get_attribute("src") for ele in WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img.img")))])
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  print([ele.get_attribute("src") for ele in WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//img[contains(@class, 'img')]")))])
  ```